# Where is the mistake in computing $\sigma(T)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

> Suppose that $T:\ell_{2}\to \ell_{2}$ is an operator, such that $$(Tx)_{k} = \dfrac{k}{k+1}x_{k+1}$$
> Find $\sigma(T)$.

Suppose that $|\lambda|>1$. Let $x_{k}\in \ell_{2}$. Then $$\dfrac{kx_{k+1}}{k+1}-\lambda x_{k}$$ yields (if I am not mistaken) $$x_{k} = \dfrac{k}{k-1}x_{k-1}+\dfrac{k}{k-2}x_{k-2}\lambda +\ldots+k\lambda^{k-2}x_1$$ But then $x\notin \ell_{2}$, so $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective, hence $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ (recall that $|\lambda|>1$), which cannot be true, since $\sigma(T)$ is bounded. So, where is the mistake?

Comment: Can you explain how you concluded that $x \notin \ell^{2}$?

Comment: @geetha290krm if we take $y$ such that $y(k)>0\;\forall k$, then $x(k)$ is greater than $k\lambda^{k-2}y(1)$ and $|\lambda^{k-2}|$ is huge, given $|\lambda|>1$

Comment: Your formula for $x(k)$ in terms of $y$ seems to be off the mark.

Comment: I've set $x(1) = 0$, but without this assumption I still can't see how this is wrong... I mean, powers of $\lambda$ are still there

Comment: You cannot set $x(1)=0$. The coefficients on the right side are wrong. See if your formula holds for $k=2$.

Comment: I computed them once again and the same problem occurred. Could you provide your formula?

Comment: Answer to the original question: Every $\lambda$ with modulus less than $1$ is an eigen value and norm of the operator is $1$. This implies that $\sigma (T)=\{\lambda: |\lambda| \leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is taking $\ x_1=0\ $, whereas its value is in fact given by
$$
x_1=-\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{y_i}{i\lambda^i}\ .
$$
Including this initial condition in your recursion for $\ x_k\ $ gives
\begin{align}
x_k&=\lambda^{k-1}kx_1+k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\lambda^{k-j-1}y_j}{j}\\
&=-k\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{k-i-1}y_i}{i}+k\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\lambda^{k-j-1}y_j}{j}\\
&=-k\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{k-j-1}y_j}{j}\\
&=-\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{ky_{i+k}}{\lambda^{i+1}(k+i)}\ ,
\end{align}
and $\ x\ $, thus defined, is in $\ \ell_2\ $.

I found the value of $\ x_1\ $ (and $\ x_k\ $ too, as a matter of fact) by using the identity
$$
(T-\lambda I)^{-1}=-\lambda^{-1}\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left(\frac{T}{\lambda}\right)^i
$$
for $\ \lambda>1\ $. Offhand, I can't think of any other way of finding it.